# Need to open default mailer when i click a link in php?

Tags: php

My requirement is to open default mailer whenever i click on a link. I don't know how to do that can any one give ideas about that.

Comment: is this the one you want
check this one

<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
Send Mail</a>

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with PHP: the `a` tag is an HTML feature, and `mailto:` is a uri scheme that browsers politely implement by trying to open the default email client.  It is not possible to use server side languages to open software on client computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mailto` in `href` attribute for opening a default mail client to send an email.

`subject` & `target` attributes are optional here.

Usage example -

```
<a href="mailto:test@gmail.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
Send Mail</a>
```

For more info - http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/struct/links.html#h-13.2.2

Comment: `target` is optional , `Subject` is optional too

Comment: don't use your email please .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I am on updation spree ;)

Comment: What use is the target attribute on a mailto link?

Comment: @Mike `target` attribute is an attribute with `a` element like the `href` in terms of functionality its an optional here